# Query first model based on parameters from child model in eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 users tables with corresponding `User` and `BUser` eloquent models. I'm trying to query `User` and only return results based on parameters on `BUser`.

I'm currently doing this:

```
public function scopeMarketplace($query) {
    return $query->with(['buser' => function($q) {
        $q->where('marketplace', '=', 1);
    }]);
}
```

Which is returning all `User`s but only including `BUser` if `marketplace = 1` but I don't want to return any `User`s unless the corresponding `BUser` parameters are met. The SQL ends up being:

```
select * from `users` limit 50 offset
select * from `busers` where `busers`.`id` in ('62', '63', '99', '100', '101', '102', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '126', '128', '130', '131', '132', '142', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172') and `marketplace` = '1'
```

This gets all `User` objects and then query's `BUser` - so returns the wrong data.

The relationship in `User` for `BUser` is :

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function buser()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\BUser', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: What's the relation between the two tables?

Comment: @Bogdan currently no relationship in MySQL

Comment: To query results from one table based on another tables column value there should be a relation between them.

Comment: Ok so if I add a foreign key to link the 2 tables, Eloquent will understand this and create the correct query?

Comment: Yes, if the [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) are defined correctly in the Eloquent models.

Comment: I just noticed the tables are `MyISAM` and don't support foreign keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method:

```php
public function scopeMarketplace($query) {
    $query->whereHas('buser', function ($q) {
        $q->where('marketplace', 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: That is indeed what I am looking for. Thanks very much.